# How to change the path of a Polyline in Maps API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, path, move, polyline

There is a way to change the position of a polyline with the Google Maps API v3 in Javascript ?

A way to change the "path" option for a line already drawn ? I already changed the position of the "Circle" but not  "RadiusLine"...

**Map init code** :

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
            zoom: 13,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
            streetViewControl: false
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });

        var sunCircle = {
          strokeColor: "#c3fc49",
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: "orange",
          fillOpacity: 0.15,
          map: map,
          center: latlng,
          radius: 1500
        };

        var origin = sunCircle.center;
        var endpoint = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(sunCircle.center,sunCircle.radius,180+sunPos);

        var radiusLineSettings = {
            clickable: false,
            map: map,
            strokeColor: "orange",
            strokeWeight: 10,
            path: [origin,endpoint]
        };
        Circle = new google.maps.Circle(sunCircle);
        RadiusLine = new google.maps.Polyline(radiusLineSettings);
```

Comment: Do you need to change it programmatically?  Or make make the polyline editable and drag it?

Answer (score 6):

The solution :

```
RadiusLine.setPath(...)
```